# Angularjs ng-repeat directive issue

Tags: angularjs, jinja2

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div ng-controller="SCTestList">
        [[messages]]
        <tr ng-repeat="item in messages">
          <td>[[item.id]]</td>
          <td>[[item.carrier]]</td>
          <td>[[item.phoneNumber]]</td>
          <td>[[item.shortcode]]</td>
          <td>[[item.sentTime]]</td>
          <td>[[item.MOs]]</td>

        </tr>
    </div>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/test.js')}}"></script>


{% endblock %}
```

test.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

function SCTestList($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/MT').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.messages = data.json_list;
        });
}

SCTestList.$inject = ['$scope'];
angular.module('myApp').controller('SCTestList', ['$scope', '$http', SCTestList]);
```

json return from the http request

```
{
  "json_list": [
    {
      "MOs": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "incomingTime": "2016-02-17 03:22:55",
          "msgID": 123123132123,
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "incomingTime": "2016-01-17 03:22:55",
          "msgID": 123123132123,
        }
      ],
      "id": 1,
      "msgID": 123123132123,
      "sentTime": "2016-01-17 03:22:55",
    },
    {
      "MOs": [],
      "id": 2,
      "msgID": 123123132143,
      "sentTime": "2016-01-17 03:22:55",
    }
  ],
  "totalPages": 1
}
```

output on the page

```
[{"MOs":[{"id":3,"incomingTime":"2016-02-17 03:22:55","msgID":123123132123},{"id":2,"incomingTime":"2016-01-17 03:22:55","msgID":123123132123}],"id":1,"msgID":123123132123,"sentTime":"2016-01-17 03:22:55"},{"MOs":[],"id":2,"msgID":123123132143,"sentTime":"2016-01-17 03:22:55"}]
```

Obviously the messages object is in scope because it is being outputted on the document, but for some reason I can't get the app to loop over the array elements. Is there anything I am missing here?

If I print $index inside the ng-repeat directive, I don't see anything printed out, so it's not looping at all.

Comment: Your markup is incorrect, you have a tr inside a div. Not sure if that is the full issue, but it is certainly one.

Comment: as mentioned by @ChristoferEliasson, your markup is incorrect.  Adding a `<table>` element allows the `<tr>` to render properly.  It still doesn't iterate the `MOs`, but it does iterate the outer rows, at least.  http://codepen.io/Claies/pen/MKVbrd

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out, the obvious issues are usually the easiest to miss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is incorrect, you have a `tr` inside a `div`. Wrap the `tr` in a `table` to get valid markup.